# Piping the json body only with requirejs

Tags: javascript, json, requestjs

So I started using `requestjs` which I am happy with, but I wonder if there is some way to pipe in a fashion, like you would do with promises:

```
function foo(url) {
  return request({ "url": url, "json": true })
}
let result = foo("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
result.pipe(process.stdout)
result.on('data', console.log)
```

- with `pipe` I can't access the object itself, so I can't only stream the body
- and on doesn't respect my specification to parse the response to json

So I can't use any of those to only access the json I receive. Of course I can use `JSON.parse`, but I'm looking for some easier way to operate on the response (similar to promises) and I feel like I'm missing the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use streams?  You can always wrap request in a promise.

This is very high level but hopefully this can get you on the right path.

```
function makeRequest(params) {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(params, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(response);
    };
  });
}


const params = {
  url: 'foo.com',
  method: 'GET',
  json: true,
};

makeRequest(params)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      return Promise.resolve(response.body);
    } else if (response.statucCode === 404) {
      const err = {
        message: 'Not Found',
        code: 404,
      };
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  })
  .then(body => // do something fun with data)
  .catch(err => // handle error);
```